# Pesquisa com data no Laravel

Tags: mysql, query

Devs, boa tarde estou com o seguinte problema, tenho a sequinte query que estou executando com `DB::raw()` Do laravel, preciso que a data seja passa pra query como string com aspas simples só assim irei conseguir executar a consulta.

```
SELECT SUM(N.primeiro_turno + N.segundo_turno + N.terceiro_turno)
      ,SUB.* 
  FROM notes N, (SELECT SUM(NS.total_dia) AS TOTAL_DIA
                       ,NS.sequencing_id 
                   FROM notes NS 
                  WHERE NS.sequencing_id IN (SELECT NT.sequencing_id 
                                               FROM notes NT 
                                              WHERE NT.data_apontamento = 2018-09-25 
                                              GROUP BY NT.sequencing_id) 
                  GROUP BY NS.sequencing_id) AS SUB 
  INNER JOIN sequencings ON sequencing_id          = sequencings.id 
  INNER JOIN products    ON sequencings.product_id = products.id 
  INNER JOIN machines    ON sequencings.machine_id = machines.id 
  WHERE N.data_apontamento = 2018-09-25 
    AND N.sequencing_id    = SUB.sequencing_id 
  GROUP BY N.sequencing_id, SUB.sequencing_id, SUB.TOTAL_DIA
```

Ele não traz nenhum resultado, fiz alguns teste e cheguei a conclusão que é por causa da data, gostaria que alguem me desse uma luz de como resolver esse problema, no workbench passo as data como string, já tentei fazer essa opção, sem successo.

Comment: Qual o tipo dos campos `NT.data_apontamento` e `N.data_apontamento`?

Comment: Você está utilizando a query de que forma?

Comment: matheus e do tipo date

Comment: Alvaro estou usando DB::raw()

Comment: Você disse que fez testes e o problema é por causa da data... Então se você remover os filtros de data funciona corretamente? Obs.: Use @ e o nome da pessoa para referenciar ela nos comentários, assim é gerada uma notificação! Exemplo: @PaulinhoCaP

Comment: colocando aspas duplas nas datas não funciona?  NT.data_apontamento = "2018-
09-25", a data que você está buscando está no formato padrão mysql?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves A data que ele está informa é correta para o padrão mysql, só é precisa colocar aspas simples ou duplas como você sugeriu

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro correto funciona

Comment: @AlvaroAlves isso preciso saber de que forma coloca aspas simples no `DB:RAW()`

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro o que acontece é o seguinte como estou usando `DB:raw()` o laravel não coloca aspas simples, fiz um teste criando variavel  `$sql` e funcionou a query

Comment: $results = DB::select('SELECT HORA(created_at) as hora, COUNT(*) as contagem FROM visitas WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ? DAY) GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)', [16]);

Comment: @PaulinhoCaP Edite sua pergunta e implemente ela carinha, informando que o problema é em relação ao `DB:RAW()` e nos mostre como você está montando o SQL em seu fonte, tentarei te ajudar mas não entendo muito de laravel

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizando binding:

```
DB:RAW('SELECT SUM(N.primeiro_turno + N.segundo_turno + N.terceiro_turno)
      ,SUB.* 
  FROM notes N, (SELECT SUM(NS.total_dia) AS TOTAL_DIA
                       ,NS.sequencing_id 
                   FROM notes NS 
                  WHERE NS.sequencing_id IN (SELECT NT.sequencing_id 
                                               FROM notes NT 
                                              WHERE NT.data_apontamento = DATE_FORMAT(?,"%Y-%m-%d") 
                                              GROUP BY NT.sequencing_id) 
                  GROUP BY NS.sequencing_id) AS SUB 
  INNER JOIN sequencings ON sequencing_id          = sequencings.id 
  INNER JOIN products    ON sequencings.product_id = products.id 
  INNER JOIN machines    ON sequencings.machine_id = machines.id 
  WHERE N.data_apontamento = DATE_FORMAT(?,"%Y-%m-%d") 
    AND N.sequencing_id    = SUB.sequencing_id 
  GROUP BY N.sequencing_id, SUB.sequencing_id, SUB.TOTAL_DIA', [$data1, $data2]);
```

Comment: Observe que no select existe dois lugares onde é utilizada a data... Sua resposta esta errada ainda.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Editado

Comment: @AlvaroAlves fiz o teste e resultado da como null

Comment: @PaulinhoCaP fiz uma edição na query, teste novamente

Comment: @AlvaroAlves ainda não funcionou, mas vc me deu uma ideia talvez o `CAST` do MySQL funcione